# C is this syntax a dictionary?

Tags: c, arrays, syntax, dictionary, header

So today's exercise wants me to use this `header.h` obviously to give me the function corresponding to the operator.

```
#ifndef __HEADER__
#define __HEADER__

￼operator operator_table[] = {{"-", &function_sub}, \
{"+", &function_add}, \
{"*", &function_mul}, \
{"/", &function_div}, \
{"%", &function_mod}};

#endif
```

First thing I noticed is that `operator` type isn't defined so maybe I should `typedef` it to an `int` ?
Then the real problem start, I've read both K&R and C Primer Plus from beginning and haven't encountered this syntax, or at least I don't recognize it, is it some kind of `dictionary` ? How can I use it ?

Comment: It seems to be an array of structures, the structure (named `operator`) containing a string and a function pointer. There is no special syntax, just a normal array definition and initialization.

Comment: What doest the '/' means ? like a separator ? and how do I access the functions ?

Comment: The `\\` is part of the preprocessor, and is a line-continuation "operator". It simply means that the preprocessor will create a single line out of this for the compiler.

Comment: your comment got voted 6+ times could you make a little answer so I can accept it ? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be an array of structures, the structure (named `operator`) containing a string and a function pointer. There is no special syntax, just a normal array definition and initialization.

The `\` is part of the preprocessor, and is a line-continuation "operator". It simply means that the preprocessor will create a single line out of this for the compiler to see.

Comment: Ok but how do I get the function if I only have the operator I want "+" for example and neither the name of the sign field of the struct nor the name of the function pointer field of the struct ? Should I just define the struct ?

Comment: I'll just define it, and thanks for the '/' preprocessor thing, I had no idea!

Comment: @ItsASecret It's probably part of the exercise to create that structure and functions, unless they're in another header file?

Comment: yeah I think so too, they just provide the header and ask us to make a working program with that header so yeah they just want us to create the struct and the functions thanks !

Answer (score 3):

`operator` here is a structure. and it could be defined in this way:

```
typedef struct {
    char *op;
    int (*func)(int, int);
} operator;
```

`func` here is a pointer to a function

`function_sub`, `function_add`, `function_mul`, `function_div` and `function_mod` should be a functions defined in your c code

Comment: I think I'll do that, define the struct and just use it like that thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In C, `operator` is not a keyword (which is not the case in C++ for example), and is here used as a symbol representing a type. So either it is typedef'd somewhere or it needs defining.

Looking at the array, this is an array of structs, the structure corresponding to `operator` being made of a `char *` and a function pointer. "+" is associated to `function_add(type, type)`, and so on. `type` is not specified here as it cannot be inferred from this piece of code. The same applies to the number of arguments, I assumed 2 but this is arbitrary.

So, to use `header.h`, you have either to:

- include in your .c file the header file that defines `operator`, if it exists.
- or define it your own way without forgetting to define the functions in charge of the actual processing.

For example:

```
#ifndef __OPERATOR_HEADER__
#define __OPERATOR_HEADER__

float function_add(float, float);
float function_sub(float, float);
/* etc, the body of these function being defined in your .c file */

typedef struct operator {
    char *operator_name;
    float (*operator_function)(float, float);
};

#endif
```